# Move arguments in a layout xml

Tags: layout, configuration

Is it possible to move an `argument` defined in a `layout`?

For example I want to move the `authentication` jsComponent in `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` to be a child of my custom step. I have tried things like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    layout="1column"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout"
                    xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components"
                        xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout"
                            xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children"
                                xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps"
                                    xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children"
                                        xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- The new step you add -->
                                        <item name="custom-step"
                                            xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component"
                                                xsi:type="string">VENDOR_MODULE/js/view/custom-step</item>
                                            <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                            <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                            <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder"> 2 -->
                                            <item name="sortOrder"
                                                xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                            <item name="children"
                                                xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                                <!-- authentication component should go here -->
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="checkout.root.jsLayout.components.checkout.children.authentication"
destination="checkout.root.jsLayout.components.checkout.children.steps.children.custom-step.children" />
    </body>
</page>
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by copying/pasting the original XML, you can't use the `move` instruction to achieve this.

To remove the original component you can use the following XML:

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

Managing UI components via XML a pain in the...